# Gradle dynamic build with different name/assets from file parsed with JSON then upload to a server

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

So there is my problem :

1) Get a file, with client information from private server

2) Parse this file and create a settings file in assets with the client inforamtion, for the application

3) Build the application with the different flavor for this particular client

4) Upload those APK to the server

In resume, APK need to look like :

- applicationClient1Flavor1-1.0.0.apk
- applicationClient1Flavor2-1.0.0.apk
- applicationClient1Flavor3-1.0.0.apk
- applicationClient2Flavor1-1.0.0.apk
- applicationClient2Flavor2-1.0.0.apk
- applicationClient2Flavor3-1.0.0.apk
- applicationClient3Flavor1-1.0.0.apk
- applicationClient3Flavor2-1.0.0.apk
- applicationClient3Flavor3-1.0.0.apk

Right now, I only have the parsing, and with that I'm just trying to build APK with different name without the creation of `settings` file.

```
task buildClientAPK {
    System.out.println("======= START =======")
    def inputFile = new File("client.json")
    System.out.println("JSON: " + inputFile.toString())
    def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(inputFile)
    for (int i = 0; i < json.clients.size(); ++i){
        def name = json.clients[i].name
        System.out.println("Name: " + name)
        System.out.println("IP: " + json.clients[i].ip_address)
        System.out.println("Port: " + json.clients[i].port)
        System.out.println("SSL: " + json.clients[i].ssl)
        System.out.println("Add UDID: " + json.clients[i].add_udid_suffix)
    }
    doLast {
        System.out.println("======= END =======")
    }
}
```

Is this possible ?